# How do I specify dependencies within a .aar file

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have an Android library project that produces a .aar file. This library depends on okhttp. I do not want to bundle okhttp within the .aar. How can I specify the dependency so that the okhttp dependency is automatically added to the build.gradle of the app when the .aar is added.

For example, in an Android app's build.gradle

```
dependecies {
   compile ('mylibrary.aar:1.0')
}
```

should include the dependency for okhttp as well.

Is there something I can add to the gradle file of my library project to achieve this ?

Comment: "How do I specify dependencies within a .aar file" -- you don't, just as you do not specify dependencies within a JAR file. The concept of "dependencies" comes from an artifact repository, not the artifact. So, if you are distributing your AAR through a Maven-style repository, your POM file will have the transitive dependency information.

Comment: Will that mean that the end project will resolve these dependencies automatically without the developer having to add an extra line to the dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, the same way as it works for the dependencies that you use from Maven-style repositories (Android Support Library, popular open source libraries, etc.).

Comment: Makes sense. Is there an example that I can use ?
Also, if you could add your comments as an answer - I'll accept it

Comment: There are a few variables, most notably where the Maven-style artifact repository will be (local machine? local machine replicated to somewhere else? a dedicated Sonatype server? Maven Central? JCenter? jitpack.io? something else?). Once you settle on a place where the repository will be, you should be able to find instructions for publishing artifacts there. For example, my CWAC libraries use the `maven` plugin and the `uploadArchives` task (see [this snippet from CWAC-Provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/v0.5.2/provider/build.gradle#L62-L72)).